# How to parse a specific function name and its parameters from string?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to parse function name and its parameters to update the string contents. I'm storing function call in a string and before invoking it i need to modify it and then invoke. Following is string containing function.

```
var expression = "AreEqual  ( \"test\" ,  Obj.Prop ) && AreEqual ( 1 , 2 ) && AREeQuAl( Obj.Prop , 1 )&& AreEqual (\"\\\"\\\",\" , 2 ) AND AreEqual (',' , ',' ) AreEqual ( \"A,B\" , Obj.Prop ) ";

var expectedOutPut = "MyClass.AreEqual( new (\"test\" AS A) , new ( Obj.Prop AS A) ) && MyClass.AreEqual ( new( 1 AS A ), new ( 2 AS A) ) && MyClass.AREeQuAl( new (Obj.Prop AS A) , new ( 1 AS A) ) && MyClass.AreEqual (new ( \"\\\"\\\",\" AS A) , new ( 2 AS A)  ) && MyClass.AreEqual (new (',' AS A) , new( ',' AS A )) && MyClass.AreEqual ( new (\"A,B\" AS A) ,new ( Obj.Prop AS A) )";
```

I tried following regex but it's breaking in valid commas inside double quotes.

```
@"(AreEqual.*?\()\s*([^,]+?)\s*(?=,|$)"

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(AreEqual.*?\()\s*([^,]+?)\s*(?=,|$)";
        string input = @"AreEqual  ( ""test"" ,  Obj.Prop ) && AreEqual ( 1 , 2 ) && AREeQuAl( Obj.Prop , 1 )&& AreEqual (""\""\"","" , 2 ) AND AreEqual (',' , ',' ) AreEqual ( ""A,B"" , Obj.Prop )";

        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I still struggling with the expected outcome. Could you provide it?

Comment: Hi @MongZhu I've updated the question. Basically i'm updating every function call with MyClass.AreEqual(new ( parameter1Here AS A) ,  new ( parameter2Here AS A)  ).

Comment: its a mistake you have AREeQual and AreEqual in expected output? and in input? i suppose the name is the same...

Comment: @mjwills Actually these are expressions executed by Dynamic Linq Library. AreEqual is a function taking 2 input as objects and then compares any heterogeneous type (I.e. string and int or int decimal) for equality. Dynamic Linq Library cannot internally cast decimal to object. So i'm creating this layer which will convert user expressions input parameters to object. E.G AreEqual ( 1 , 1.0) to MyClass.AreEqual( new ( 1 as A ) , new ( 1.0 as A ) )

Comment: @Frenchy Yes, Names are the same, Basically i want regex to be case-insensitive. The regex i written was able to parse AreEqual in first group and first input parameter of function in 3rd group. But it was failing when it encounters comma inside double quote I.e. AreEqual("My,Data" , "My,Data" ).

Comment: Let's narrow the task: do you want to support interpolated, verbatim, all types of C# string literals?

Comment: I don't get it. How is this part `AreEqual (\"\\\"\\\",\" , 2 )` supposed to look in real text? really like this: `AreEqual ("\"\"," 2)` ? or is it supposed to look like this:  `AreEqual ("\", 2)` ?

Comment: The quotes are easy to handle if these are simple C string literals. I see that `AND` looks like `&&` in the expected result and `&&` that was missing before the last `AreEqual` is added in the expected output. Are these typos?

Comment: you cant do that with only one match, you have complex case...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, i want to support all types of c# literals.

Comment: Then there is no solution with regex. If it were just regular `'`/`"` delimited string literals, I'd post [this code](https://ideone.com/gwCoS3).

Comment: @MongZhu AreEqual ("\"\"," 2). Basically to some complexity i considered this clause.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry && , and  are typos. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to match the items into groups and then format a new string using those groups.

```
string pattern = @"(AreEqual)\s*\((\s*[\""']*[\w,\\]*(.\w+)*[\""']*\s*),(\s*[\""']*[\w,\\]*(.\w+)*[\""']*)\s*\)";
string input = @"AreEqual  ( ""test"" ,  Obj.Prop ) && AreEqual ( 1 , 2 ) && AREeQuAl( Obj.Prop , 1 )&& AreEqual (""\""\"","" , 2 ) AND AreEqual (',' , ',' ) AreEqual ( ""A,B"" , Obj.Prop )";

RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

List<string> expectedOutputParts = new List<string>();
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    string newstring = $"MyClass.{m.Groups["1"]}( new ({m.Groups["2"]} AS A) , new ({m.Groups["4"]} AS A) )";
    expectedOutputParts.Add(newstring);         

}   

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" && ", expectedOutputParts));
```

Output:

> `MyClass.AreEqual( new ( "test"  AS A) , new (  Obj.Prop AS A) ) && MyClass.AreEqual( new ( 1  AS A) , new ( 2 AS A) ) && MyClass.AREeQuAl( new ( Obj.Prop  AS A) , new ( 1 AS A) ) && MyClass.AreEqual( new (','  AS A) , new ( ',' AS A) ) && MyClass.AreEqual( new ( "A,B"  AS A) , new ( Obj.Prop AS A) )`

Disclaimer:

this version does not contain the `AreEqual (""\""\"","" , 2 )` part. I still haven't figured that out.

Comment: i tried this but it is failing at Empty brackets "". https://regex101.com/r/iZ5bYH/3

Comment: @MaheshJadhav the we have to change `[\w,\\]+` to make it optional: `[\w,\\]*` . empty brackets were not part of your example. I edited my post. [Now it works](https://regex101.com/r/iZ5bYH/5)

Comment: @MaheshJadhav can you tell me how you match the case that I did not catch?

Comment: var regex = @"(AreEqual)\s*\((\s*[\"')(+&!$*>=:\/\\<]*[\w,\\]*(.\w+)*[\"')(+&!$*>=:\/\\<]*\s*),(\s*[\"')(+&!$*>=:\/\\<]*[\w,\\]*(.\w+)*[\"')(+&!$*>=:\/\\<]*)\s*\)". this rescued me.

Comment: public string GetExp(string expression){ string specialChars = @"\""')(+&!$*>=:\/\\<";
            string pattern = @"(AreEqual)\s*\((\s*[" + specialChars + @"]*[\w,\\]*(.\w+)*[" + specialChars + @"]*\s*),(\s*[" + specialChars + @"]*[\w,\\]*(.\w+)*[" + specialChars + @"]*)\s*\)";

            var options = RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

            return Regex.Replace(expression, pattern, m => m.Groups[1].Value + "( new ( " + m.Groups[2] + " as Object ) , new ( " + m.Groups["4"] + " as Object ) )", options);}

Answer (score 0):

here is a generic solution:

```
        var texte = "AreEqual  ( \"test\" ,  Obj.Prop ) && AreEqual ( 1 , 2 ) && AREeQuAl( Obj.Prop , 1 )&& AreEqual (\",\" , 2 ) AND AreEqual (',' , ',' ) AreEqual(\"A,B\", Obj.Prop)";

        //Extract function
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(texte, @".+?(?=\()");
        var function = Regex.Matches(texte, @".+?(?=\()")[0].ToString().Trim();


        var patternARGS = @"(?<=\().+? (?=\))";
        var patternExtractARGS = @"""[^, ]* , [^, ]*""( , )""[^, ]* , [^,]*""|[^, ]* , [^, ]*""( , )[^""]+""|[^""]+( , )""[^,]* , [^,]*""|( , )";

        // extract all arg between parenthesis
        matches = Regex.Matches(texte, patternARGS);

        //extract all args from previous result, with the difficulty to identify the right ','
        List<String> args = new List<String>();
        foreach (Match m in matches)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{m}");
            MatchCollection x = Regex.Matches(m.ToString(),patternExtractARGS);
            GroupCollection commas = x[0].Groups;

            var index = (commas.SyncRoot as Match).Index;
            var len = (commas.SyncRoot as Match).Length;
            var a1 = m.ToString().Substring(0, index);
            var a2 = m.ToString().Substring(index + len - 1);
            args.Add($"MyClass.{ function}( new ({a1}), new ({a2}))");
        }


        //extract conditions && AND...)
        var patternCONDITION = @"(?<=\)).+?(?=(?i: " + function + "))";
        matches = Regex.Matches(texte, patternCONDITION);



        var output = args[0];
        for(int i = 1;i<args.Count;i++)
        {
            output = output + $" {matches[i - 1].ToString().Trim()} {args[i]}";
        }
```

result in output.

Comment: i tried this but its expecting all expression containing 'AreEqual' function and failing at  : var texte = " 2 == 4 && AreEqual  ( \"test\" ,  Obj.Prop ) && AreEqual ( 1 , 2 ) && AREeQuAl( Obj.Prop , 1 )&& AreEqual (\",\" , 2 ) AND AreEqual (',' , ',' ) AreEqual(\"A,B\", Obj.Prop)";